# Linear regression: Why derviative = 0 is the minimum for OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, derivative, extreme-value

I am new in this field, but I wanna advance fast and wan't to have a complete picture of everything. I have a very simple question, but I guess I am missing something in imagining the whole picture. Maybe I cannot imagine the graph of $\epsilon'\epsilon$ also $(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)$ correctly.

So I want to know why in order to minimize $\epsilon'\epsilon$ we need to solve the derivative with respect to $\beta$ to be equal to zero. I understand that when the derivative is zero the tangent is horizontal. But how do we know we are at a minimum. Can't we be at a maximum or a local minimum or a local maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\epsilon' \epsilon$ is a quadratic function, there is only one minimum, which is global. And this minimum is found with the first derivative of the function.